# Minimum spanning tree and cycles

Tags: graph, graph-theory, minimum-spanning-tree

Can a minimum spanning tree have a cycle IF the weighted cost of the edge which makes the cycle is ***0***? Since this would not change the weight could it still be considered a minimum spanning tree?

Comment: A tree *by definition* has no cycles

Comment: thanks Harold, in that case I mean could it still be considered a minimum spanning graph?

Comment: I suppose so, it's a bit unusual though

Comment: If there is at least one edge in your cycle with weight > 0, you could delete this edge and get a spanning graph of lesser weight ( an mst if there has only been a single cycle ).

Answer (score 0):

This question can be answered by properly considering the definitions of a MST. Trees, by definition contain no cycles. Therefore, even a cycle that is created with a zero weighted edge could not be part of the tree. We could remove this zero-weighted edge to make it a tree again. However, to make it a MST, we would have to remove the highest-weighted edge that's part of the cycle (note that I'm assuming that the premise of your question assumes that the only thing making the spanning graph not minimal and not a tree is the cycle).

You mentioned the idea of a minimum spanning graph (MSG - that's not a real acronym because, for reasons explained, this isn't really a thing). This isn't really a useful concept because in every case *except* a zero-weighted edge, the MST *is* the MSG. All trees can be disconnected by removing just one edge. Therefore, they have no extraneous edges - so adding another edge to make it a graph will just increase the weight. The exception to this is the zero-weighted edge - adding it wouldn't add any weight. Theoretically, you could add as many zero weighted edges as you wanted to an MST to make any number of MSGs. However, this isn't a very interesting property for two reasons:

1. the MST will always be a subgraph of any MSG so most any analysis can be done of the MST - with less complexity since there's fewer edges.
2. There's basically no real world situation that's modeled by a graph where a 0-weighted edge makes sense. In a highway system, every road segment has some length. In every circuit, every wire has some resistance. Even if you discovered a zero weighted edge for any of these examples (like a wire with 0 Ohms of resistance, setting aside the physical impossibility of such a thing), you would still want the MST because the monetary cost of your zero-weighted edge is assuredly non-zero.